# Lua function expects two parameters even when I have declared the function with one parameter

Tags: lua

Consider the Lua code below:

```
local util = {}

function util:foo(p)
  print (p or "p is nil")
end

util.foo("Hello World")
util.foo(nil, "Hello World")
```

When I run this in lua console, I get following result:

```
p is nil
Hello World
```

Can somebody explain this behavior to me.

**Edit**
I got the code working by making following change:

```
local util = {}

function util.foo(p)
  print (p or "p is nil")
end

util.foo("Hello World")
util.foo(nil, "Hello World")
```

I am fairly new to Lua, so any pointers/links explaining this behavior will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

When you declare the function using the : syntax there is an unspecified parameter 'self' which is the object the function is working on.  You can call the method using the colon syntax:

`util:foo("Hello World")`

If you use the dot notation, you are referencing the function as an entry in the util table and you have to pass 'self' yourself.

With foo declared with a colon, these two calls are equivalent:

```
util:foo("Hello World")
util.foo(util, "Hello World")
```

To declare this the same with the dot syntax you would do this:

```
function util.foo(self, p)
  print (p or "p is nil")
end
```

or

```
util.foo = function(self, p)
  print (p or "p is nil")
end
```

Comment: How do I invoke the `foo` method directly?

Comment: Thanks, the link helped me understand the concept.