# function arguments expected

Tags: lua, lua-table, metatable

I'd like to accomplish one thing with metatablitz, but i don't understand how to do it right. More precisely, i implemented it, but i miss one little thing - so that in the right place i can use a colon.

The code below is simple and speaks for itself. How do i make sure that Z:Entity.Create() does not cause an error?

```
Z = {
  Entity = {
    Create = function(name)
      print ('Entity name:', name)
    end,
  }
}

setmetatable(Z.Entity, {__call = function(self, ...)
  print (...)
end})

local p1 = Z:Entity('New entity')  -- table: 0xb8f730 New entity
p1 = Z.Entity.Create('test')  -- Entity name: test
p1 = Z:Entity.Create('test')  -- lua: [string "<eval>"]:16: function arguments expected near '.'
```

Any advice or help would be welcome!

Comment: What is `Z:Entity.Create('test')` supposed to do? You can fix the error by using a dot instead of a colon, like in the statement before it.

Answer (score 2):

`a:name()` is syntactic sugar for `a.name(a)`

So if you write `Z:Entity.Create('test')`, the interpreter expects `Entity` to be a function value. But instead of the expected function arguments in parenthesis there is a dot.

Your code doesn't make too much sense though. Why do you assign three different things to `p1`?

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't really self explanatory, you need to explain what you are trying to do and why you *want* to use a colon.  I recommend reading up on the syntax, maybe with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983263/lua-function-expects-two-parameters-even-when-i-have-declared-the-function-with/4983304#4983304).  The colon basically is a shortcut for calling a function on an object and passing the object as the first parameter.  When defining a function using the colon syntax it lets you skip declaring the 'self' parameter and declares one behind the scenes.

Let's look at your three sample statements:

**First statement:**

```lua
local p1 = Z:Entity('New entity')
```

That is equivalent to this:

```lua
local p1 = Z.Entity(Z, 'New entity')
```

Since you set a metatable for Z.Entity with `__call`, you can use call the Entity table as a function.  Since you use the colon syntax, it passes Z as the first parameter when calling the function so you are really passing two parameters.  The way it is declared then, `self` will be `Z.Entity` and `...` will expand to the two arguments, `Z` and `'New entity'`.

**Second statement:**

```lua
p1 = Z.Entity.Create('test')
```

Here you are simply calling the function 'Create' and passing it the string 'test' prints out `Entity name: test`.  You are not using colon syntax and the metatable `__call` function isn't being executed because you are not calling Entity like a function.

**Third statement:**

```lua
p1 = Z:Entity.Create('test') 
-- lua: [string "<eval>"]:16: function arguments expected near '.'
```

When you write `Z:Entity`, it expects you to be calling it as a function and it will pass Z as the first argument to that function.  It doesn't make any sense to have a period following Entity.

**Possible assumption**

From the name `Entity.Create`, it sounds like you want to create a new object with this function and return it.  ***This*** is where you would normally return a new table and call `setmetatable` and specify `__index` which will look for the the passed object to find functions that can be called.  You should read up on [object oriented programming in LUA](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.1.html), but here's a quick example of what I think you're *trying* to do:

```lua
Z = {
  Entity = {
    SayHello = function(self)
      print(self.name .. " says 'Hello'!")
    end,

    Create = function(name)
      local obj = {}
      obj.name = name
      setmetatable(obj, {__index = Z.Entity})
      -- now you can call obj:SayHello()
      return obj
    end
  }
}

local p1 = Z.Entity.Create('Player 1')

-- here p1 is passed as the first argument to SayHello because
-- a colon is used
p1:SayHello()  -- Player 1 says 'Hello'!
```